# ¿Como centrar menú desplegable?

Tags: html, html5

Tengo el siguiente de código el cual saque de un foro que es de un menú desplegable, pero lo quiero tener centrado, supuestamente en el foro te da el código ya centrado pero no, y he estado investigando sobre como centrarlo en distintas páginas pero sin suerte no he encontrado nada y en realidad no se cómo hacerlo.

Si me pueden ayudar, muchas gracias, lo necesito.
Aquí el código:

Las partes que se agregaron supuestamente al código para centrarlo están en forma de comentarios para poder identificarlos

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Menu Desplegable</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        * {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }

        #header {
            margin:auto;
            width:500px;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        ul, ol {
            list-style:none;
        }

        .nav {
            width:500px; /*Le establecemos un ancho*/
            margin:0 auto; /*Centramos automaticamente*/
        }

        .nav > li {
            float:left;
        }

        .nav li a {
            background-color:#000;
            color:#fff;
            text-decoration:none;
            padding:10px 12px;
            display:block;
        }

        .nav li a:hover {
            background-color:#434343;
        }

        .nav li ul {
            display:none;
            position:absolute;
            min-width:140px;
        }

        .nav li:hover > ul {
            display:block;
        }

        .nav li ul li {
            position:relative;
        }

        .nav li ul li ul {
            right:-140px;
            top:0px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <nav> <!-- Aqui estamos iniciando la nueva etiqueta nav -->
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Servicios</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu4</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Submenu4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Acerca de</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav><!-- Aqui estamos cerrando la nueva etiqueta nav -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar con

```
nav {
display:flex;
}
```

y en la clase .nav quitas el width:500px;

Comment: No me funcionó, tengo un contador aparte y eso lo centro en vez de el menú

Comment: ¿Podrías poner como tienes actualmente tu header a ver si otros pueden ayudarte?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar a centrarlo entre las etiquetas situadas en el body de tu menú, al inicio de las etiquetas del menú deberías colocar estas etiquetas como envolviendo tu menú.

```
    <html>
    <head>

    codigo css

    </head>
    <body>
<div id="header">
        <center>

                <nav> <!-- Aqui estamos iniciando la nueva etiqueta nav -->
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Servicios</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu4</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Submenu4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Acerca de</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Submenu4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>    
     </center>

   </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Recuerda que es importante cerrar las etiquetas abiertas.

Comment: No me funciona, es raro

Answer (score 0):

```
    .nav {
        width:500px; /*Le establecemos un ancho*/
        margin:0 auto; /*Centramos automaticamente*/
        text-align: center;
        background: red;
    }

    .nav > li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: da un breve explicacion de tu respuesta.